# Chat feed bots seem unusually slow recently

Tags: bug, chat, feed

In my experience, chat feed bots — the ones that post feed messages into the chat directly — are usually pretty fast. Our bot on RPG Stack Exchange reliably has posted new Meta posts to the chat after about 10 minutes.

Recently however they seem pretty slow:

- We're noticing [board game's Metagamer chat bot is slow](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34992992#34992992); a meta post from 22:46 didn't show up until 00:45.
- Literature's Bookworm chat bot has been reliably slow. [It recently took 40 minutes to make a post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35026633#35026633), and [it's been like that for ages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34951370#34951370) (we've started making jokes about the "worm" name), and [some of us are concerned it's slow to the point of *missing* messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=34933810#34933810).
- In Role-Playing Games I've noticed our Oracle chat bot being slow since December, when it took [until 1:13 AM to post a meta from 00:29 AM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34197039#34197039). Mostly though it's been fast, posting our messages within a few minutes like normal.

Is this just coincidence, or temporary, or a deliberate part of how the chat bot works? Right now a few chats are noticing behaviour about it being slow and unreliable and I'm not sure if it's just our imagination or not.

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287173/feeds-fails-to-feed-a-chatroom-regularly

Comment: Please see [Nick Craver's answer to "HNQ RSS feed stopped updating"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293496/134300).